# Passing Table Rows & Single Variable together in Controller Response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a controller in Laravel that currently looks like this

```
public function index($merchant_url_text)
{
$deals = DB::table('tbl_deal')
            -> join ('tbl_merchant', 'tbl_deal.merchant_id', '=', 'tbl_merchant.merchant_id')
            -> where ('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)->get();
    return $deals;
}
```

What I want to add to this controller is another query.

```
$merchant_name = DB::table('tbl_merchant')->where('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)->value('merchant_name');
```

How do I make sure I can return just the single merchant_name along with the current rows that are being passed in $rows

Answer (score 0):

Just return both of them in an associative array:

```
return array(
  'merchant_name' => $merchant_name,
  'deals' => $deals,
);
```